# Why is my page loading without any css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this problem has been bugging me for a few days now. I've been trying to get a working nightmode switch on my site. I've asked on here before and after what I thought was the solution, using help from this site and stack exchange, I started experiencing an annoying problem.

Here is a video of my problem: https://ryan-simms.com/problem

The problem only occurs when nightmode is enabled and I don't understand what the actual problem is. I've tried all sorts of different JavaScript codes with the same result everytime. Also before anyone says it's because of the DOMContentLoaded bit, I have already tried removing it on only using it when adding the EventListeners on my buttons.

Also I tried to change the way getCookie() works with a few different methods.

Are cookies the right way or is there a better way?

Here is my HTML stripped down to the basics:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

  <title>Ryan Simms</title>

<link id ="pageStyle" rel="stylesheet" href='css/lightStyle.css' type='text/css'>
<script src="scripts/lightSwitch.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/cookie.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' type='text/css'>


    </head>

    <body>
    <script src="lightSwitch.js"></script> <!-- Loads LightSwitch Script -->

  <button type="button" id="lightSwitchOn">Turn On Night Mode</button>
  <button type="button" id="lightSwitchOff">Turn Off Night Mode</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoad);

function handleDocumentLoad() {

  var style = document.getElementById("pageStyle");
  var offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff");
  var onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn");

  offSwitch.addEventListener('click', lightsOn);
  onSwitch.addEventListener('click', lightsOff);

  function lightsOff() {
    document.cookie = "lights = off;  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
    style.setAttribute('href', 'css/darkStyle.css');
  }

  function lightsOn() {
    document.cookie = "lights = on;  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
    style.setAttribute('href', 'css/lightStyle.css');
  }

  function getCookie( name ) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    var end = null;
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
        end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    } else {
        begin += 2;
        end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
            end = dc.length;
        }
    }

    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end) ).replace(/"/g, '');
} 


  function checkCookie() {
    var nightmode = getCookie("lights");
    if (nightmode == "off") {
      lightsOff();
    } else {
      lightsOn();
    }
  }

  checkCookie();
 }
```

Here is my default CSS:

```
/*Layout for phones and tablets e.g. iPhone 5 and iPad*/

    /*webpage fades in*/
    html {
        animation: fadein 2s;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    /*animation*/
    @keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to { opacity: 1; }
    }

    /*main colour settings for page*/
    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #1C1C1C;
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin: 0 0 100px;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    /*List in nav*/
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
    }

    /*Navigation*/
    nav {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #D8D8D8;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    ol {
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    /*Links*/
    a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*Main heading*/
    h1 {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*Images*/
    img {
        border: solid 0px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    textarea {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid 1px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 2px;
        resize: none;
    }

    input {
        border: solid 1px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #logo {
        border: 0px;
        display: inline;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 30px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #enter {
        margin-top: 40px;
        max-width: 90%;
        max-height: 90%;
    }

    video {
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }

    /*Footer*/
    footer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*Main Body*/
    #mainContent {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #D8D8D8;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    #mainContent img {
        display: inline;
        max-width: 375px;
        max-height: 375px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    /*Light Switches*/
    #lightSwitchOn {
        display: inline;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        right: 30px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #lightSwitchOff {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        right: 30px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #cookies {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 8%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #D8D8D8;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

/*Layout for device with a min-width of 1024px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

    #enter {
        max-width: 60%;
        max-height: 60%;
    }
}

/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1280px (720p HD)*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

    #enter {
        max-width: 40%;
        max-height: 40%;
    }
}

/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1920px (1080p HD)*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {

    #enter {
        max-width: 40%;
        max-height: 40%;
    }
}
```

And my CSS when night mode is enabled:

```
/*Layout for phones and tablets e.g. iPhone 5 and iPad*/

    /*webpage fades in*/
    html {
        animation: fadein 2s;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    /*animation*/
    @keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to { opacity: 1; }
    }

    /*main colour settings for page*/
    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0 0 100px;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    /*List in nav*/
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
    }

    /*Navigation*/
    nav {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #1C1C1C;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    ol {
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    /*Links*/
    a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover {
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*Main heading*/
    h1 {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*Images*/
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        border: solid 0px #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    textarea {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid 1px #FFF;
        border-radius: 2px;
        resize: none;
    }

    input {
        border: solid 1px #FFF;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #logo {
        border: 0px;
        display: inline;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 30px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #enter {
        margin-top: 40px;
        max-width: 90%;
        max-height: 90%;
    }

    video {
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }

    /*Footer*/
    footer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*Main Body*/
    #mainContent {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #1C1C1C;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    #mainContent img {
        display: inline;
        max-width: 375px;
        max-height: 375px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    /*Light Switches*/
    #lightSwitchOn {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        right: 30px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #lightSwitchOff {
        display: inline;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        right: 30px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #cookies {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 8%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #1C1C1C;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

/*Layout for device with a min-width of 1024px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

    #enter {
        max-width: 60%;
        max-height: 60%;
    }
}

/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1280px (720p HD)*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

    #enter {
        max-width: 40%;
        max-height: 40%;
    }
}

/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1920px (1080p HD)*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {

    #enter {
        max-width: 40%;
        max-height: 40%;
    }
```

}

Comment: You probably don't want things like your home address and phone number on the video?

Comment: It’s on my personal website, I’m okay with it

Comment: He means that in about 23.5 minutes you're gonna be bombarded with sales calls and literal bombs at your doorstep because you gave away your personal information online.

Comment: It's been up for weeks now and I've had none of them, any number I don't recognise I don't answer and eventually block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are cookies the right way or is there a better way?

Since you don't care about the cookie on the server side, prefer [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You can replace all of your cookie code with things like

```
localStorage.setItem('lights', 'off');

if(localStorage.getItem('lights') === 'off') { ... }
```

Instead of loading a new stylesheet for your night mode, consider adding a `.dark` class to your `body` if night mode is on and incorporating the appropriate changes in your main stylesheet.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    padding: 25px;
}

body.dark {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: black;
}

/*Navigation*/
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.dark nav {
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
}
```

Comment: Another solution is to use Less.js for browser side compilation of Less stylesheets, so you can pass new variable values to your less files to change the colors. Go to Less.js if this interests you, they have pretty good guides.

Comment: I think it may have worked, I tried a go at local storage earlier but wasn't too familiar with it also thanks for the tip I'll check it out!